# Logstash custom matching

Tags: regex, logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

```
  AppliedProperty_PurchaseStatus = (string) <SOLD>
  AppliedProperty_UrlText = (string) <http://www.dummyurl.com>
  MA_Number= (decimal) [123456789]
```

I'm trying to figure out how to do some matching with grok while importing logs for applications. But to be frank I am fairly lost, how would i go about matching above so i can search for "MA_Number" and get "123456789" as the result in elastic

Comment: Use something like `MA_Number\s*=\s*\(decimal\)\s*\[%{NUMBER:num}]` ([pandaadb's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39572722/3832970) seems viable, just name the variable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regular Expression for that number, assuming there each line is processed one-by-one, with grok, would be:

```
MA_Number= \(decimal\) \[%{NUMBER}\]
```

NUMBER is a pattern defined by grok, alongside a lot of patterns that can help you:

https://github.com/elastic/logstash/blob/v1.4.2/patterns/grok-patterns

With regards to the messages you provide above (which do not match your grok at all (??))

This is how you can quickly test this/deploy this:

My test config:

```
input {
stdin{}
}


filter {

    grok {
       match => ["message", "MA_Number= \(decimal\) \[%{NUMBER:num}\]" ]
    }

}


output {
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

The test:

```
artur@pandaadb:~/dev/logstash$ ./logstash-2.3.2/bin/logstash -f conf3/
Settings: Default pipeline workers: 8
Pipeline main started
MA_Number= (decimal) [123456789]
{
       "message" => "MA_Number= (decimal) [123456789]",
      "@version" => "1",
    "@timestamp" => "2016-09-19T13:30:56.837Z",
          "host" => "pandaadb",
           "num" => "123456789"
}
```

See how the number of the message has been extracted into the variable num.

Comment: Uh yea, thought it would be easier to modify the config. But I have to swallow my pride and ask for help again, if you look at my edit in the post. How would you implement that row? Tried a few things but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: The grok in your config does not match the example log statements you gave at all

Comment: No I realise that, I can't figure out how to add your example even.

Comment: @Jakodns i created a minimal config based on the messages that you provide with the grok matching the number

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\[([0-9]+)\]`, it will match:

- [ litteral
- 1 or more numbers
- ] and a closing bracket

https://regex101.com/r/sP3gA7/2

Demonstration

```js
var re = /\[([0-9]+)\]/; 
var str = '  AppliedProperty_PurchaseStatus = (string) <SOLD>\n  AppliedProperty_UrlText = (string) <http://www.dummyurl.com>\n  MA_Number= (decimal) [123456789]';
var m;
 
if ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    console.log(m[1]);
}
```

https://regexper.com/#%5C%5B(%5B0-9%5D%2B)%5C%5D